# Unable to create a new connection using Navicat in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on my ubuntu. Everything are installed in `/opt/lampp` directory.

When I run `localhost/phpmyadmin`, it is working fine and I can create database as well.

But when I try to setup using Navicat, it is returning me

`2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")`

My server is also running `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

I have used following configuration:

```
Host: localhost
Port: 3306
User Name: root
Password: my_password
```

Can anybody please help me here.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Use 127.0.0.1 ip address instead of localhost to connect to MySQL.

**Reason:**
When using localhost to connect to MySQL, the operating system will use the socket connector.

If you use the 127.0.0.1 ip address, the operating system will use the TCP/IP connector.